# WordPress ignoring LIMIT / posts_per_page despite being in wp_query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Using WP query:

```
$myquery = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => $instance['count'], 'meta_key' => 'mywp_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC'  ) );
```

Let's get the request:

```
echo $myquery->request;
```

It returns:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'mywp_post_views_count' ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

This runs correctly in MySQL, giving me 5 post ID's. But WordPress returns 120 results!

```
echo '$myquery = ' . count( $myquery->posts );
```

returns: $myquery = 120

And I've checked when looping through:

```
 while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post();
```

It does output the 120 unique posts, rather than the expected 5 posts.

I can confirm:

```
echo 'Count: '.$instance['count'];
```

Returns: Count: 5

I am running the latest stable WordPress (4.1), with no plugins apart from ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) - just my custom theme. Disabling this plugin has no effect, and default WordPress theme (2015) has the same issue.

I'm struggling to understand why this is happening.

Comment: What is `$instance['count']`?

Comment: Why is your query `$myquery`, but the variable you're looping through `$popularpost`?

Comment: you should ask this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try to set `paged => 1` or `page => 1` in WP_Query params.

Comment: $instance['count'] is 5, and apologies that's a typo $myquery is being looped - not popular post. Above post corrected now. I've also tried paged => 1 and page => 1, but still returns 120 results unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Check if `$instance['count']` has the desired value for posts_per_page. For example, if you want 5 posts, `$instance['count']` should be `= 5`;

```
$instance['count'] = 5; //just for the sake of the test
```

Comment: Actually, I think this does answer the question, it's just phrased in a way such that your superficial reading assumed it was asking for clarification.

Comment: I can confirm $instance['count'] is 5, echo 'Count: '.$instance['count']; returns Count: 5

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked 6 years ago, but this still was driving me crazy, so maybe it'll help someone. There are two options that I needed for posts_per_page to work:

```
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true,
        'paged'                 => 1,
```

I've tried to use them separately and it didn't help, only when both are set everything works fine.

Comment: 'ignore_sticky_posts' is definitely a valid suggestion to look out for. I've fallen into that trap before. Be careful of hard-coding the 'paged' value to '1' though. This number needs to represent the current paginated page number. Using something like the following value is probably better: get_query_var( 'paged' )

Comment: Yes, I should've mentioned the meaning of the 'paged' option. In my case, it should be 1 as I use it for showing sticky posts on the top of the page but it may not be the case for someone who is looking for this answer. Thank you for adding this

Answer (score 0):

for resolve  just define array out of WP_Query!
like this:

```
$args=[
'category_name'  => '',
'posts_per_page' => $home_post_count,
'paged'          => $paged];
```

$query = new WP_Query( $args);